# TV Hisense HLE4815RT not tuning cable signal

Tags: voltage-regulator, repair, ldo, tv, tuner

I have a **Hisense TV HLE4815RT** (mainboard: **RSAG7.820.5649**), that suddenly stopped tuning cable signal, it just says "*No signal*". I tried different cables, removing some splitter, reprogramming the channels and still doesn't get a signal on any channel. A different TV works on the same cables. A few times, ramdomly, when turning it on it picks up the signal for 1 second with normal quality, and then loses it.

All the other functions work fine, hdmi and usb port (have a chromecast connected), all the smart functions and everything else works normally. That's why I suspect it may be an issue on the tuner. I do not have any experience repairing TVs, I just like electronics and do some arduino stuff as a hobby.

I opened the TV to check for any obvious issue like a burnt component but couldn't find anything. I measured the voltages on the tuner pins:

[image]

And see that where it says **3v3** it's actually receiving **3.69v**. In the datasheet for the voltage regulator **1117A** (*N19* in the pic) that seems to power the tuner, it says **Max Vout** is **3.366v**. In google, I found that the tuner (**CDT-9051324-10**) uses the chip **NXP 18273**, whose datasheet shows a **Max Vin** of **3.6v**.

The **Vref** measured between the **GND/ADJ** and **Vout** pins of the **1117** regulator have **1.35v** (in the datasheet it says it should be **1.25v**). The two resistors *R398* and *R399* have the correct value according to *page 14* of [these diagrams](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jkAunm0KcOZ-RGhvxUGutZhCArHreuTT/view) (**110** and **180** ohms).

***Is the 3.69v coming from the regulator between the acceptable range or could it be malfunctioning and causing the tuner to not work?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vref should be 1.25V between 3.69-2.29=1.4V

In order to lower Vout to 3.3 you must add resistance between those two pins to lower Vout.

IDK the R values used, start with 220 to 470 Ohms to get a 3.3V output .

Vref is either 1.4 or 1.35 shown due to incorrect R values.. It is between ADJ and should be Vout-Vadj = 1.25V. The R =Values they used may have tried to get 3.6Vmax but due to tolerances (10%?) failed to achieve that.

[image]

Link not avail, but site is shown.